# Identifying the basic information of Windows installation .iso images

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, iso-image, windows-installation

I've 6 different *Windows 8.1 64-bit / 32-bit* installation .iso images. All of the 6 images are untouched and officially released by Microsoft. How could I identify the basic information of each .iso image? 
The basic information that I need to know how identify: (**Type of image**: is RTM, RTL, VL, or OEM), (**Release Date**), (**Image Version**), (**Update / Rollup Updates included**), and (**Servicepack version**).
I've searched for how to do that, but unfortunately none of the methods I found worked for all the information I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Run `Dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:"E:\sources\install.wim"` to see which SKUs are included in the WIM. Now open the `idwbinfo.txt` on the DVD/ISO under sources, here you see if it is 32 or 64Bit and if it is a debug (checked) or the normal (retail) version.

Comment: I still can't get these attributes:
**Release Date**: ex. `10/17/2013`, **RTM BUILD**: ex. `6.3.9600.16384.WINBLUE_RTM.130821-1623`, and **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD**: ex. `9600.16404.WINBLUE_GDR.130913-2141`.

What I successfully able to get:
**Type of image** (identified from `idwbinfo.txt`), and **Servicepack version**

Comment: the only way to get this is selecting the properties of a file like setup.exe and look at the file information.

Comment: I'm now successfully able to get the **RTM BUILD** via the setup.exe file information. How about the **Release Date**, **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD**?

Comment: for new ISOs which have rollups, the setup.exe also gets updated.

Comment: How could I get the **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD** number from the setup.exe? I've tried and I can get the **RTM BUILD** number only!!

Comment: check the versioninfo of the setup.exe in the sources folder, not the one from the root dir.

Comment: Unfortunately, both the setup.exe files (in the root dir. and the sources folder) have the version of **RTM BUILD**!! I'm now having only the **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD** and the **Release Date** remaining.

Comment: I can see in the December ISOs from MSDN this version: 6.3.9600.17483

Comment: The ISO I'm testing is released on October, The **RTM BUILD** is _6.3.9600.16384_ and it confirms what I've got from the ISO. The **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD** should be `9600.16404`, I think, or something like `9600.16404.WINBLUE_GDR.130913-2141`. I need to be able to get the **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD** and **Release Date** from the ISO, not the MSDN.

Comment: this looks like a selfmade ISO. My way only works for official ISOs. Btw, why do you need those information?

Comment: No, what I'm having are official ISOs downloaded from MSDN (and confirms the official hash announced on the MSDN website), but unfortunately they aren't available now on MSDN, I don't know why.
What alternative can I use to get the **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD** and the **Release Date**?

Comment: I have no idea. Download the last ISO from december 2014 which has the November Update included. this is the latest version which Microsoft offers.

Comment: The idea is that I want to classify the .ISOs I have, I need to identify all the information I've mentioned for every .ISO I'm having. I still not able to identify **ROLLUP UPDATE BUILD** and the **Release Date** as mentioned before.